# Reshape/melt a dataframe for scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
x   ys --------------------->
1   20   25   30   12   22   12
2   12    9   12   32   12 
3   33   12   11    6    1
4    5   10   41   12    3
5    7   81   12   31    8   3   4   11
```

I'd like to make a scatter plot with one x value and multiple y values (ys).  I was trying to use reshape with melt, but I couldn't get the proper data structure created to make this plot. How can I do this in R and plot with ggplot? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what did not work with `melt`? And what Problems did you have with `geom_point()`? Hard to say if this is what you want:

```
library( "reshape2" )
library( "ggplot2" )

df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(20), ya = rnorm(20), yb = rnorm(20), yc = rnorm(20) )
df <- melt(df, id.vars="x", variable.name="class", value.name="y")

ggplot( df, aes( x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_point( aes(colour = class) )

ggplot( df, aes( x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( "class" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't have header names for the data. Note that there are many columns of y values so value.name="y" won't work for me.

Comment: @user1728853 If your data.frame doesn't have header names, why don't you just spend it some some: `colnames( df ) <- c("ya", "yb", ...)` ? Additionally, `value.name` is not the name of columns in the original data.frame but the name of the value column after melting. If this example didn't bring your desired output, you should tell us, what you tried so far and maybe provide a reasonable subset of your data. See `? dput`for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matplot` function.

Assuming your data is in an object called `myDat` and that the `x` values are in column `1` and the `y` values are in the other columns,

```
matplot(x = myDat[, 1], y = myDat[, -1], type = "p", pch = 21)
```

would produce something like

[image]

Or using the `latticeExtra` package for the `ggplot2like` theme:

```
library(latticeExtra)

xyplot(as.formula(paste(paste0(names(myDat)[-1], collapse = "+"), "~",
  names(myDat[1]))),
  data = myDat, par.settings = ggplot2like(), grid = TRUE)
```

[image]